# Multer Upload single not working in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I have tried multiple online resources to upload a file to a destination on the local machine. This console shows that the file has been uploaded but the file is not seen in the destination folder. This is my server.js code:

```
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser())
app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.hbs')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App is live on port ${port}`)
})

app.post('/upload', upload.single('myFile'), (req, res, next) => {

  console.log('called')
  console.log(req.body.myFile)

  if (req.body.myFile) {
    console.log('Uploading file...')
    var filename = req.body.myFile

    var uploadStatus = 'File Uploaded Successfully'
  } else {
    console.log('No File Uploaded')
    console.log('======================== SESSION END ========================')
    var filename = 'FILE NOT UPLOADED'
    var uploadStatus = 'File Upload Failed'
  }

  /* ===== Add the function to save filename to database ===== */

  res.render('index.hbs', { status: uploadStatus, filename: `Name Of File: ${filename}` })
})
```

Here is my index.hbs file:

```
<form action="/upload"  method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="myFile"  required />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"  />
</form>
```

Can somebody please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in your hbs.
The form misses the attribute: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

PS: `req.body` should contains the extra data (such as text fields), to output your file you should check `req.file`.

It is all in the doc: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#readme